# Microsoft FaceId - Instanciar FaceClient

Tags: c#, api, microsserviços

Olá,

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação utilizando os serviços cognitivos Microsoft em especifico o FaceId, entretanto estou com um problema na inicialização da biblioteca, peguei esse código no próprio site da Microsoft:

```
FaceClient faceClient = new FaceClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey), new System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] { })
{
    Endpoint = faceEndpoint
};
```

Entretanto quando o cursos passa por essa linha de código ele da o seguinte erro:

> {"Regras de segurança de herança foram violadas pelo tipo:
>   'System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler'. Os tipos derivados devem
>   corresponder à acessibilidade de segurança do tipo de base ou ser
>   menos acessíveis.":"System.Net.Http.WebRequestHandler"}

Não consegui achar nada na internet que explicasse isso, conto com a sabedoria de vocês, obrigado!

Comment: Segundo a documentação da Microsoft, [Example: How to identify faces in images](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtoidentifyfacesinimage), para inicializar o serviço basta fazer `faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("<Subscription Key>");`.

Comment: Não existe a classe faceServiceClient na versão 2.0 somente FaceClient

Answer (score 0):

Segundo a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/tutorials/faceapiincsharptutorial) do SDK CSharp:

```
// Troque <SubscriptionKey> com sua chave de inscrição.
// Por exemplo, subscriptionKey = "0123456789abcdef0123456789ABCDEF"
private const string subscriptionKey = "<SubscriptionKey>";

// Troque ou verifique seu endPoint.
//
// Você deve usar a mesma região usada para obter sua chave de inscrição
// Por exemplo, se você obteve suas chave de inscrição do
// westus region, substitua "Westcentralus" por "Westus".
//
// NOTA: As chave de inscrição de avaliação gratuita são geradas no westcentralus
// por isso, se você estiver usando uma chave de inscrição de avaliação gratuita,
// não precisa mudar esta região.
private const string faceEndpoint =
    "https://westcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com";

private readonly IFaceClient faceClient = new FaceClient(
    new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials(subscriptionKey),
    new System.Net.Http.DelegatingHandler[] { });
```

lembrando que é necessário utilizar as importações:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face;
using Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Vision.Face.Models;
```

---

De acordo com essa outra [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/face/face-api-how-to-topics/howtodetectfacesinimage) você deve estar fazendo da seguinte maneira:

Etapa 1: autorize a chamada da API

Cada chamada para a API Face requer uma chave de inscrição. Essa chave precisa ser passada por um parâmetro de string de consulta ou especificada no cabeçalho da solicitação. Para passar a chave de inscrição por meio da string de consulta, consulte o URL de solicitação do [Face-Detect](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f30395236) como um exemplo:

```
https://westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/detect[?returnFaceId][&returnFaceLandmarks][&returnFaceAttributes]&subscription-key=<Subscription Key>
```

Como alternativa, a chave de inscrição também pode ser especificada no cabeçalho da solicitação de HTTP: ocp-apim-subscription-key:  Ao usar uma biblioteca cliente, a chave de assinatura é passada pelo construtor da classe FaceServiceClient. Por exemplo:

```
faceServiceClient = new FaceServiceClient("<Subscription Key>");
```

Seria apenas fazer isso e já funcionaria ok.

Comment: Boa tarde Gunblades, obrigado pela resposta, mas dentro da biblioteca não existe a classe faceServiceClient, somente FaceClient versão 2.0

Comment: Outra coisa, o primeiro jeito que você me passou da o mesmo erro !